# GPGS Undefined symbols for architecture: on Xcode 8.0/Sierra 10.12

Tags: ios, xcode, google-play-games

When you build the project with

```
pod 'Google/SignIn'

pod 'GooglePlayGames'
```

It gets error.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_GTMMethodCheckMethodChecker", referenced from:
>   +[NSDictionary(GTMNSDictionaryURLArgumentsAdditions) xxGTMMethodCheckMethodNSString32] in GTMNSDictionary+URLArguments.o
>   +[NSDictionary(GTMNSDictionaryURLArgumentsAdditions) xxGTMMethodCheckMethodNSString33] in GTMNSDictionary+URLArguments.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image: Error from Xcode 8]

I uploaded this problem [on the GTM's issue page](https://github.com/google/google-toolbox-for-mac/issues/128) and [PlayGameService's issue page](https://github.com/playgameservices/cpp-ios-basic-samples/issues/9), It seems GPG isn't currently maintained.

perotinus, the developer of GTM said

> GooglePlusOpenSource pod that it depends on. My guess is that the GooglePlusOpenSource pod has a precompiled version of GTM that doesn't have its symbols renamed, and the linker gets confused when it sees that in the set of libraries that it should use when trying to link the GTM pod.

Is there any possible idea to use it? I don't see downgrade is not the good option.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm facing exactly this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error for installation of pod Firebase/Auth and I install older version of GoogleToolboxForMac above Firebase/Auth that is pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac', '2.0.0'.After that firebase with compatible version of GoogleToolboxForMac start to install.On your podfile remove pod 'Google/SignIn' and pod 'GooglePlayGames'. Paste pod of older version of GoogleToolboxForMac  just above pod 'Google/SignIn' and pod 'GooglePlayGames' and install it again.

pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac', '2.0.0'

pod 'Google/SignIn'

pod 'GooglePlayGames'

Comment: This didn't solve it for me. I am facing the exact same problem.